Simplifying adjacent polygons with Python while maintaining shared borders
I want to simplify adjacent polygons (GADM zones level 1) with Python while maintaining shared borders.
The general problem is well explained at Simplifying Polygonal Coverages with JTS. The best external tool I found is https://mapshaper.org/
There are already some Q&As about this problem in this site like Generalizing polygon file while maintaining topology in QGIS. Unfortunately, I have not yet found a solution which I can easily use in Python.
Do you have tips for a function of a specific package?
I also thought about using GRASS in Python.  I think v.generalize is what I am looking for.

I've just tried the topojson solution in the duplicate question and it works nicely on a test set of UK subregions, and the adjacency matrix is preserved.

I just found this Q&A which is helpful (using topojson):
Geopandas simplify results in gaps between polygons
And I found out that the JTS algorithm is supposed to be downstreamed to shapely (a Python package). Unfortunately, I don’t know when this will be implemented but it is mentioned at the end of the blogpost:
http://lin-ear-th-inking.blogspot.com/2023/03/simplifying-polygonal-coverages-with-jts.html?m=1
